# Upload Amazon S3 videos to Facebook via PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, api, amazon-s3

I'm creating an application which need to upload a video to a user profile on Facebook (web hosted application, I am using Facebook PHP SDK). Videos are hosted on Amazon S3.

I have tried to upload a video that is hosted locally on my instance, and that is working fine (authentication is OK, and the video is found to be uploaded).

But I am not able to find how to directly retrieve the video on S3 to upload it. I have read that this could be done only when the video is local. But that is not convenient for me to download the video from S3 first then upload it to Facebook.

**Has anybody faced this issue, and found a way to solve it so that the video can be directly uploaded from S3 to Facebook, using the S3 Url ?**

Thanks a lot for your help.